# WordPress database error Table './databasename/wep_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired for query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

Please help me my mysql is keep crashing again and again and generating following error i am out of any clue what will be the reason for this issue

> WordPress database error Table './databasename/wep_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired for query SELECT option_value FROM wep_options WHERE option_name = '_otgs_twig_cache_disabled' LIMIT 1 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/RIVIERA/404.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/RIVIERA/header.php'), do_action('icl_language_selector'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WPML_LS_Actions->callback, WPML_LS_Public_API->render, WPML_LS_Render->render, WPML_LS_Template->get_html, WPML_Templates_Factory->get_view, WPML_Templates_Factory->maybe_init_twig, WPML_Templates_Factory->is_caching_enabled, get_option, referer: http://www.jjweem.com/A/?C-1-348.Html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using MyISAM Engine

**Don't use MyISAM for any case**. It's becoming deprecated.

---

To get rid of this problem first repair your table.

Do the following:

```
REPAIR table wep_options;
```

Depending on the table size, this command takes time.

If your table is big and you can stop temporary mysql, I think myisamchk command is faster than repair command.

Check out end of this topic:
[https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/myisamchk/#repairing-tables][1]

After that To avoid repeating crash convert all tables to InnoDB Engine.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE your_tables ENGINE=InnoDB;
```